# How to call .cshtml view file from index.html file?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have an MV Studio MVC Project. It is running well. I have created one root page namely, Index.html. I would like to call "View/Account/Login.cshtml" page from "Index.html" page.

I have tried below options:
a href="/Account/Login">Log in /a> a href="~/Controllers/Account/Login">Log in /a>

The following screenshots have project and error view:
http://my.jetscreenshot.com/29065/20161202-ysmx-69kb

http://my.jetscreenshot.com/29065/20161202-lphy-32kb

Reply me if anyone has a good solution to an issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use

```html
 <a href="@Url.Action("Login", "Account")">Log in </a>
```

Where "Login" is action method and "Account" is controller name.
This will render your login.cshtml view.

Dont use anyone of these

a href="/Account/Login">Log in /a> 
a href="~/Controllers/Account/Login">Log in /a>

Answer (score 1):

The path is not correct in the given link:

http://my.jetscreenshot.com/29065/20161202-ysmx-69kb

It should be *`localhost:2300/Account/Login`*

ex.

```
<a href="/Account/Login">Login</a>
```

You don't need to add a
Every MVC application must configure (register) at least one route, which is configured by MVC framework by default. You can register a route in RouteConfig class, which is in RouteConfig.cs under App_Start folder. The following code illustrates how to configure a Route in the RouteConfig class.

```
 routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
               name: "Default",
               url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
               defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

Please find a link for more information below:
http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/routing-in-mvc

Answer (score 0):

Use URL helper instead of hard coding the links as the code could break if you change your routing configuration in future.

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")">This</a>
```